# Yii2 How do I use multiple array keys with the same value inside attributeLabels function

Tags: php, arrays, function, duplicates, yii2

I am creating a column inside a table that can have 0, 1, 2 or 3. All these numbers have a certain value, in my case 0 = DOG, 1 = CAT, 2 = FISH, 3 = FROG. To get the names inside the table instead of the numbers I do the following:

```
public function attributeLabels(): array
{
    return [
        Pet::DOG => 'Dog',
        Pet::CAT => 'CAT',
        Pet::FISH => 'Fish',
        Pet::FROG => 'Frog',
        Pet::TYPE_LAND => 'Land',
        Pet::TYPE_WATER => 'Water'
}
```

And in the Gridview

```
[
    'attribute' => 'Animal',
    'header' => Icon::show('beast', ['title' => Yii::t('backend', 'animal')]),
    'value' => function ($model) use ($petSearch) {
         return $petSearch->getAttributeLabel($model['Animal']);
     },
     'filter' => [
         Pet::DOG => $PetSearch->getAttributeLabel(Pet::DOG),
         Pet::CAT => $PetSearch->getAttributeLabel(Pet::CAT),
         Pet::FISH => $PetSearch->getAttributeLabel(Pet::FISH),
         Pet::FROG => $PetSearch->getAttributeLabel(Pet::FROG),
     ]
],
```

This should show me the column with the right translations and it does, but there is a problem. Sinds TYPE_LAND and TYPE_WATER also have the values 0 and 1 it gives me a mix of the 2 so the column makes no sense for instance instead of dog I see Land. I also get the following message in my code:

```
Duplicate array key with value '0'
```

Is there a way to make this work correctly

Comment: You can not use the same array key more than once, the second occurrence will overwrite the first. _"Sinds TYPE_LAND and TYPE_WATER also have the values 0"_ - they shouldn't though. Using the _same_ numeric value for multiple constants in the same context, that simply is a mistake.

Comment: The problem is that they get these values in my database and I can't change them. Is there another way to get both of them in the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `attributeLabels()` method for this. That method is supposed to label model's attributes not its values.

You can create two public methods for translating values into proper labels in your `PetSearch` model for example like this:

```
public function animalLabel($animal) {
    $map = [
        Pet::DOG => 'Dog',
        Pet::CAT => 'CAT',
        Pet::FISH => 'Fish',
        Pet::FROG => 'Frog',
    ];

    if (isset($map[$animal])) {
        return $map[$animal];
    }
    // ... do something if the value is not present in map
    // for example throw an exception, return empty/default label or something...
}

public function animalTypeLabel($type) {
    $map = [
        Pet::TYPE_LAND => 'Land',
        Pet::TYPE_WATER => 'Water'
    ];

    if (isset($map[$type])) {
        return $map[$type];
    }
    // ... do something if the value is not present in map
    // for example throw an exception, return empty/default label or something...
}
```

Then in your GridView config use those methods to replace numeric value with label:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'Animal',
    'header' => Icon::show('beast', ['title' => Yii::t('backend', 'animal')]),
    'format' => function ($value) use ($petSearch) {
         return $petSearch->animalLabel($value);
    },
    'filter' => [
        Pet::DOG => $petSearch->animalLabel(Pet::DOG),
        Pet::CAT => $petSearch->animalLabel(Pet::CAT),
        Pet::FISH => $petSearch->animalLabel(Pet::FISH),
        Pet::FROG => $petSearch->animalLabel(Pet::FROG),
    ],
],
[
    // asuming the type value is in `AnimalType` attribute - change to match your attribute names
    'attribute' => 'AnimalType',
    'header' => Icon::show('beast', ['title' => Yii::t('backend', 'animal')]),
    'format' => function ($value) use ($petSearch) {
         return $petSearch->animalTypeLabel($value);
     },
    'filter' => [
        Pet::TYPE_LAND => $petSearch->animalTypeLabel(Pet::TYPE_LAND),
        Pet::TYPE_WATER => $petSearch->animalTypeLabel(Pet::TYPE_WATER),
    ],
],
```

Comment: Only the map inside of animalLabel should _not_ have Pet::TYPE_LAND and Pet::TYPE_WATER in there any more ... Right now, your code still has the exact same problem - those would overwrite the first two map entries.

Comment: @CBroe You're right. Thanks. Typical copy&paste issue... I've edited my answer to fix it.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Thanks! The only problem still is that the filter doesn' t show like this.

Comment: @TLausie I've edited answer to add the filter config. It's done exactly same way.